# I can't figure out this room calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help on getting it to ask the shape of the room, listed below, the floor type they want, listed below, and ask these for how ever many rooms are being calculated. Along with printing the price per room, and the total for all rooms. The result of running it is below all of the code.

```
carpet = 25
vinyl = 17
hardwood = 31
concrete = 18


def circle():
    r = float(input('What is the radius of the room?:    '))
    pi = 3.14
    room_size = pi * r **2
    return (room_size)


def rectangle():
    b = float(input('What is the length the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('What is the width of the room?:    '))
    room_size = b * h
    return (room_size)
 

def regular_polygon():
    p = ('What is the perimeter of the room?:   ')
    a = ('What is the Apothegm of the room?:    ')
    room_size = p * a / 2
    return (room_size)
    

def trapezoid():
    b1 = float(input('What is the length of the bottom base of the room?:   '))
    b2 = float(input('What is the length of the top base of the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('How far apart are the top base and bottom base?:  '))
    room_size = h * (b1 + b2) / 2
    return (room_size)

    
def triangle():
    b = float(input('What is the length the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('What is the width of the room?:    '))
    room_size = (b * h) / 2
    return (room_size)

    
def floor(floorings):
    floorings = input('What floor type would you like?:   carpet, vinyl, hardwood, or concrete.')
    if floorings == ('carpet'):
        floor_type = carpet
    elif floorings == ('vinyl'):
        floor_type = vinyl
    elif floorings == ('hardwood'):
        floor_type = hardwood
    elif floorings == ('concrete'):
        floor_type = concrete
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid room shape: ' + equation_type)
    
    return floor_type
    

number_of_rooms = int(input('How many rooms will we be calculating?:   '))


def rooms(room_shape):
    total_area = 0
    for i in range(room_shape):
        equation_type = input('What is the shape of the room (circle, rectangle, regular polygon, trapezoid, triangle)?   ').lower()
        if equation_type == ('circle'):
           total = (total_area + circle())
        elif equation_type == ('rectangle'):
           total = (total_area + rectangle())
        elif equation_type == ('regular polygon'):
            total = (total_area + regular_polygon())
        elif equation_type == ('trapezoid'):
            total = (total_area + trapezoid())
        elif equation_type == ('triangle'):
            total = (total_area + triangle())
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid room shape: ' + equation_type)

    return total
room_count = number_of_rooms


print (('$'), rooms(room_count) * floor)
```

What is the width of the room?:    2
What is the shape of the room (circle, rectangle, regular polygon, trapezoid, triangle)?   rectangle
What is the length the room?:   5
What is the width of the room?:    2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/••••••/Desktop/coputer coding/Flooring estimator.py", line 100, in 
print (('$'), rooms(room_count) * floor)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'

Comment: Hi Jakob, welcome to Stack Overflow. There's no need to apologize for being new to coding, we've all been there before. What would help us answer your question is some more details about what the problem you're having is. Can you show some example runs where it doesn't work right? What is your code doing now, and what do you expect it to be doing instead? If you're getting any exceptions, show us the full stack trace (or at least a representative part of it if it's excessively long).

Comment: Sure, basically whats going on is that it wont ask what type of floor you'd like, and I also don't know how to get the equation to properly work either. It will just return that I can only use multiplication on float and functions. Here is exactly what its returning.

Comment: The code is slightly incorrect since the floor function is called incorrectly. Would you want help rectifying how to fix that ?

Comment: What do you expect `rooms(room_count) * floor` to do? `floor` is a function...

Comment: I am trying to get it to get it to basically take the area of the type of rooms and multiply the cost of the floor type wanted for the individual rooms.

Comment: Tanishq Vyas, yes if possible.

Comment: I have added the answer explaining steps of execution and issue in the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code had two issues :

```
1. print (('$'), rooms(room_count) * floor)
```

Here the floor function is called by writing `floor` whereas it actually should have been `floor()`

```
2. floor(floorings)
```

You do not need the `floorings` parameter since you are taking that as the input from the user.

This is the corrected code :

```
carpet = 25
vinyl = 17
hardwood = 31
concrete = 18


def circle():
    r = float(input('What is the radius of the room?:    '))
    pi = 3.14
    room_size = pi * r **2
    return (room_size)


def rectangle():
    b = float(input('What is the length the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('What is the width of the room?:    '))
    room_size = b * h
    return (room_size)
 

def regular_polygon():
    p = ('What is the perimeter of the room?:   ')
    a = ('What is the Apothegm of the room?:    ')
    room_size = p * a / 2
    return (room_size)
    

def trapezoid():
    b1 = float(input('What is the length of the bottom base of the room?:   '))
    b2 = float(input('What is the length of the top base of the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('How far apart are the top base and bottom base?:  '))
    room_size = h * (b1 + b2) / 2
    return (room_size)

    
def triangle():
    b = float(input('What is the length the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('What is the width of the room?:    '))
    room_size = (b * h) / 2
    return (room_size)

    
def floor():
    floorings = input('What floor type would you like?:   carpet, vinyl, hardwood, or concrete : ')
    if floorings == ('carpet'):
        floor_type = carpet
    elif floorings == ('vinyl'):
        floor_type = vinyl
    elif floorings == ('hardwood'):
        floor_type = hardwood
    elif floorings == ('concrete'):
        floor_type = concrete
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid room shape: ' + equation_type)
    
    return floor_type
    

number_of_rooms = int(input('How many rooms will we be calculating?:   '))


def rooms(room_shape):
    total_area = 0
    for i in range(room_shape):
        equation_type = input('What is the shape of the room (circle, rectangle, regular polygon, trapezoid, triangle)?   ').lower()
        if equation_type == ('circle'):
           total_area = (total_area + circle())
        elif equation_type == ('rectangle'):
           total_area = (total_area + rectangle())
        elif equation_type == ('regular polygon'):
            total_area = (total_area + regular_polygon())
        elif equation_type == ('trapezoid'):
            total_area = (total_area + trapezoid())
        elif equation_type == ('triangle'):
            total_area = (total_area + triangle())
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid room shape: ' + equation_type)

    return total_area
room_count = number_of_rooms


print (('$'), rooms(room_count) * floor())
```

Now here is the execution explanation for the corrected code

1. The user is asked to input the number of rooms he wishes to calculate the results for. This value is read in the `number_of_rooms` variable.
2. Then the **total cost** for the purchase/calculations is found out by summing the individual costs of **flooring** and **total cost for all the rooms** which is calculated using the `rooms(room_shape)` function.
3. The `rooms(room_shape)` function repeats a set of steps for all the rooms. The steps being calculating the **floor area of each room** and adding it to the overall floor area which is tracked by using the `total_area` variable.
4. Once the total area for all the rooms is calculated based on the input from user where he/she selects the type of room they wish, the value of `total_area` is returned.
5. This is then added to the value returned from the `floor` variable. Thus giving you the final cost.

However this floor cost is added just once and is not at all calculated the way you expect it to be calculated. I suppose to calculate it for each room where each room may have different type of flooring such as

```
total_cost = room_area1 * floor1 + room_area2 * floor .... so on
```

For that you should use the code which looks something like this :

```
carpet = 25
vinyl = 17
hardwood = 31
concrete = 18


def circle():
    r = float(input('What is the radius of the room?:    '))
    pi = 3.14
    room_size = pi * r **2
    return room_size * floor()


def rectangle():
    b = float(input('What is the length the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('What is the width of the room?:    '))
    room_size = b * h
    return room_size * floor() 

def regular_polygon():
    p = ('What is the perimeter of the room?:   ')
    a = ('What is the Apothegm of the room?:    ')
    room_size = p * a / 2
    return room_size * floor()
    

def trapezoid():
    b1 = float(input('What is the length of the bottom base of the room?:   '))
    b2 = float(input('What is the length of the top base of the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('How far apart are the top base and bottom base?:  '))
    room_size = h * (b1 + b2) / 2
    return room_size * floor()

    
def triangle():
    b = float(input('What is the length the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('What is the width of the room?:    '))
    room_size = (b * h) / 2
    return room_size * floor()

    
def floor():
    floorings = input('What floor type would you like?:   carpet, vinyl, hardwood, or concrete : ')
    if floorings == ('carpet'):
        floor_type = carpet
    elif floorings == ('vinyl'):
        floor_type = vinyl
    elif floorings == ('hardwood'):
        floor_type = hardwood
    elif floorings == ('concrete'):
        floor_type = concrete
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid room shape: ' + equation_type)
    
    return floor_type
    

number_of_rooms = int(input('How many rooms will we be calculating?:   '))


def rooms(room_shape):
    total_area = 0
    for i in range(room_shape):
        equation_type = input('What is the shape of the room (circle, rectangle, regular polygon, trapezoid, triangle)?   ').lower()
        if equation_type == ('circle'):
           total_area = (total_area + circle())
        elif equation_type == ('rectangle'):
           total_area = (total_area + rectangle())
        elif equation_type == ('regular polygon'):
            total_area = (total_area + regular_polygon())
        elif equation_type == ('trapezoid'):
            total_area = (total_area + trapezoid())
        elif equation_type == ('triangle'):
            total_area = (total_area + triangle())
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid room shape: ' + equation_type)

    return total_area
room_count = number_of_rooms


print (('$'), rooms(room_count))
```

Here the only change being, `floor()` is called for each room instead of being called once after calculation of net area.

But the current code still has an issue where `total` and `total_count` are not used correctly to add and update the net area. Instead to get the prices of individual rooms you could use the following method :

```
carpet = 25
vinyl = 17
hardwood = 31
concrete = 18


def circle():
    r = float(input('What is the radius of the room?:    '))
    pi = 3.14
    room_size = pi * r **2
    return room_size * floor()


def rectangle():
    b = float(input('What is the length the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('What is the width of the room?:    '))
    room_size = b * h
    return room_size * floor() 

def regular_polygon():
    p = ('What is the perimeter of the room?:   ')
    a = ('What is the Apothegm of the room?:    ')
    room_size = p * a / 2
    return room_size * floor()
    

def trapezoid():
    b1 = float(input('What is the length of the bottom base of the room?:   '))
    b2 = float(input('What is the length of the top base of the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('How far apart are the top base and bottom base?:  '))
    room_size = h * (b1 + b2) / 2
    return room_size * floor()

    
def triangle():
    b = float(input('What is the length the room?:   '))
    h = float(input('What is the width of the room?:    '))
    room_size = (b * h) / 2
    return room_size * floor()

    
def floor():
    floorings = input('What floor type would you like?:   carpet, vinyl, hardwood, or concrete : ')
    if floorings == ('carpet'):
        floor_type = carpet
    elif floorings == ('vinyl'):
        floor_type = vinyl
    elif floorings == ('hardwood'):
        floor_type = hardwood
    elif floorings == ('concrete'):
        floor_type = concrete
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid room shape: ' + equation_type)
    
    return floor_type
    

number_of_rooms = int(input('How many rooms will we be calculating?:   '))


def rooms(room_shape):
    total_area = []
    for i in range(room_shape):
        equation_type = input('What is the shape of the room (circle, rectangle, regular polygon, trapezoid, triangle)?   ').lower()
        if equation_type == ('circle'):
           total_area.append(circle())
        elif equation_type == ('rectangle'):
           total_area.append(rectangle())
        elif equation_type == ('regular polygon'):
            total_area.append(regular_polygon())
        elif equation_type == ('trapezoid'):
            total_area.append(trapezoid())
        elif equation_type == ('triangle'):
            total_area.append(triangle())
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid room shape: ' + equation_type)

    return total_area
room_count = number_of_rooms


rooms_cost = rooms(room_count)
for room_cost in range(len(rooms_cost)):
    print (f"The cost for room {room_cost+1} is ${rooms_cost[room_cost]}")
print("\nTotal Cost : ", sum(rooms_cost))
```

Comment: Omg thank you, but if it's not to much to ask I do have a few follow up questions on somethings.

Comment: Please feel free to ask. Also if the answer helped you then please accept the answer and upvote it to let other know it worked.

Comment: Okay so if I wanted it to return the individual price per room, what would I do, because right now it seems to only be pringting one of the prices.

Comment: In order to do that you could simply calculate price for each room inside the for loop. Instead of adding it to the total_area, just make the total_area a list and  keep appending the individual prices to that list. In the end return that list. Also I have updated the answer a bit to accomodate the improper addition.

Comment: How would I go about changing that with out messing up most of the other parts?

Comment: I will update the answer accordingly wait.

Comment: Okay, and thank you for being so willing to help.

Comment: My pleasure. If this helped you, please upvote and accept (green tick) the answer so that any new user may know that this answer proved correct and helpful.

Comment: So I actually managed to get it to do what I needed without using a list, the only problem is that it is asking the question as to what type of floor they'd like 1 to many times any idea?

Comment: I added, print (('$'), rooms(room_count) * floor()), but I can't seem to understand why even though I input that I was calculating 2 rooms, it asked me just the carpet question one extra time. It also will return $6250.0, instead of the $525 that it would return even if it was adding the extra time it asked for a floor type

Comment: for an idea, I am telling it I am calculating 2 rooms, then saying rectangle, and I put in 5 and then 2, then I say I want carpet. Then it asks me the shape of the second room, I input the same as above, and after I put in carpet for the floor of the second room, it will ask me again for a floor type. If it didn't ask an extra time it should return $500, and even if it added the extra input, wich when asked the third time, I still input carpet. It should only output $525.

Comment: Never mind I fixed it, I will say thank you so much for the help and I did upvote your reply, but because of my public level it isn't publicly visable.

Comment: @JakobGoodfriend Accept the answer, (green tick) that will be visible